# Duplicating multiple powerpoint slides using docx4j

Tags: java, powerpoint, docx4j

I'm trying to duplicate a couple slides using docx4j but I am running into some trouble.

I have a .pptx file with 3 pages and I am looking to duplicate each page several times. This is my code so far (based off samples from [here](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/src/samples/pptx4j/org/pptx4j/samples):

```
    PresentationMLPackage presentationMLPackage = (PresentationMLPackage) OpcPackage.load(new File(args[0]));

    MainPresentationPart pp = (MainPresentationPart)presentationMLPackage.getParts().getParts().get(
            new PartName("/ppt/presentation.xml"));

    List<SlidePart> slideParts = pp.getSlideParts();

    int index = 1;

    for(SlidePart slidePart : slideParts){

        SlideLayoutPart layoutPart = (SlideLayoutPart)presentationMLPackage.getParts().getParts().get(new PartName("/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout" + index + ".xml"));
        Sld copied = XmlUtils.deepCopy(slidePart.getContents(), slidePart.getJAXBContext());

        SlidePart slide = new SlidePart(new PartName("/ppt/slides/slide" + index + ".xml"));
        slide.setContents(copied);

        pp.addSlide(1, slide);

        slide.addTargetPart(layoutPart);

        index++;
    }

    presentationMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("test.pptx"));
```

My code runs fine without any errors and when I open the file, I am alerted of an error within the powerpoint and it asks to repair the file and when you do, the page is blank and the page did not duplicate.

How do I get this working properly?

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, this isn't so straight forward.  You need to take care of the slide rels etc.

For this reason, we have a commercial solution in Docx4j Enterprise, which you can find at https://www.plutext.com/m/index.php/products

Comment: I'm aware of the commercial solution but I am just a student working on this as a personal project, is there no way this can be done using the non-enterprise version?

Comment: Well, the enterprise version does its thing using docx4j, so in principle you can do it using just docx4j as well, but there is a fair bit to take care of.  Since you are a student working on a personal project, please send me an email, and we'll help you out.